# react custom hook causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am relatively new to react hooks and I am trying to create this custom hook to handle CRUD operations for my API.

This is the hook file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useApi = (url, headers = { method: "GET" }, payload = null) => {
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null);
  const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(null);
  const [api, setApi] = useState({});

  const list = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(url);
      const data = await resp?.json();
      setApiData(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setServerError(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const create = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(url, (headers = { method: "POST" }), payload);
      const data = await resp?.json();
      setApiData(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setServerError(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  setApi({
    ...api,
    list: list,
    create: create
  });

  return { isLoading, apiData, serverError, api };
};

export default useApi;
```

However, when I call api.list() in my main component inside a useEffect() hook, I get an infinite loop.

Sample component call:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useApi from "./useApi";

export default function App() {
  
  const {
    isLoading: loading,
    apiData: students,
    serverError: error,
    api
  } = useApi("https://59f0f160ce72350012bec011.mockapi.io/students");

  console.log(loading, students, error, api);

  useEffect(() => {
    api.list();
  }, [api]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>list</h1>
      {loading ? "loading" : students.map((x) => x.name)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the sandbox for it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-chebyshev-d9q89?file=/src/App.js:0-492

Can anyone help me understand the issue?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what is causing the infinite loop:

```js
setApi({
  ...api,
  list: list,
  create: create
});
```

You are not supposed to call setState() during a render.

In your case, you don't need to `useState` for the api object, you can just return it on every render:

```js
return {
  isLoading,
  apiData,
  serverError,
  api: { list, create }
};
```

[Here is a link to the fixed sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bash-ty8kk?file=/src/useApi.js:870-954)

Also, another warning: this code will repeatedly call `api.list()`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  api.list();
}, [api]);
```

Since `api` changes on every render, it will repeatedly call `api.list()`.

This is the object that changes on every render:

```js
return { isLoading, apiData, serverError, api };
```

You can ensure that you only call `api.list()` one time by using a ref.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'

// In the component
const gotRef = useRef(false)
useEffect(() => {
  if (!gotRef.current) {
    api.list();
    gotRef.current = true
  }
}, [api]);
```

Comment: Thanks @programmerRaf. I have added the ref, but it still gives me the infinite loops.
You can see the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-chebyshev-d9q89?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @rsilva I found the real cause of the infinite loop. I edited the answer.